# Laravel casts with relation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm making a survey website where users provide answers from 0 to 10.
I was experimenting with the **casts** to store all questions and the answer in 1 row.

This is what the scores field looks like in the database

```
{"5":8,"6":8}
```

This is as expected. The "5" and "6" are ID's of the question and the 8's are the scores provided by the user.

I'm wondering if it's possible to query the answers but include a relation to the question. I would like to see the results as follows

```
{"5" => {"question: ...", "answer: ..."}
```

> So my question: is it possible to cast to an array but include relations in Laravel? Or will I need to loop the array and fetch the question data for each row.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe this is not possible. I think you should loop through your array and use `Question::find($id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with custom accessors and mutators, but I would not recommend storing the relation in the db. You don't want references whole objects in there that might change independently, so keep it to ids and decorate your output after fetching scores from the db.

```
public function getScoresAttribute($value)
{
    // if using casts to array, this should already be done
    $scores = json_decode($value, true);

    $questions = Question::whereIn('id', array_keys($scores))->get();
    $rs = [];

    $questions->each(function($q) use ($rs, $scores) {
        $rs[$q->id] = [
            'question' => $q->toArray(),
            'answer'   => $scores[$q->id],
        ];
    });

    return $rs;
}
```

Now you can just do something like:

```
dd($survey->scores);
```

And you'll get the decorated data.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Your answer was my old solution. Now days, I have a new solution for this! There is the my answer.

We need to create a new trait for Foo model. Firstly create "Relations" and "Relation" folders under laravel's "app" folder. "Relation" folder is inside the "Relations" folder.

**This answer is just supporting one dimensional array relationship. You can edit this make perfect...**

"app/Relations/Relation" Finally this is the full folder path structer.

**This is the "app/Models/Foo.php" Model file source.**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use App\Relations\HasBarRelations;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Models\Bar;

    class Foo extends Model
    {
        use HasBarRelations; // Trait

        protected $table = "foo";
        protected $fillable = ["bar"];

        protected $casts = [
            "bar" => "array" // Array cast
        ];

        public function bar()
        {
            return $this->belongsToBar(Bar::class, "id", "bar"); // Relationship
        }
    }
```

**And there is the "app/Relations/HasBarRelations.php" file source;**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Relations;

    use App\Relations\Relation\BarRelation;

    trait HasBarRelations
    {
        /**
         * Define a custom relationship.
         *
         * @param string $related
         * @param null $foreignKey
         * @param null $localKey
         * @return HasBarRelations
         */
        public function belongsToBar($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
        {
            $instance = new $related;
            $query = $instance->newQuery();

            return new BarRelation($query, $this, $foreignKey, $localKey);
        }
    }
```

**After that create a new file called "app/Relation/BarRelation.php" under Relation folder. This file's source code is need to be like that;**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Relations\Relation;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class BarRelation extends Relation
    {
        /**
         * The baseConstraints callback
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $foreignKey;
        protected $localKey;

        /**
         * Create a new belongs to relationship instance.
         *
         * @param Builder $query
         * @param Model $parent
         * @param string $foreignKey
         * @param $localKey
         */
        public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, $foreignKey, $localKey)
        {
            $this->foreignKey = $foreignKey;
            $this->localKey = $localKey;

            parent::__construct($query, $parent);
        }

        /**
         * Set the base constraints on the relation query.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function addConstraints()
        {
            if (static::$constraints) {
                $this->query->where($this->foreignKey, '=', $this->getParentKey());

                $this->query->whereNotNull($this->foreignKey);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get the key value of the parent's local key.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getParentKey()
        {
            return $this->parent->getAttribute($this->localKey);
        }

        /**
         * Set the constraints for an eager load of the relation.
         *
         * @param  array  $models
         * @return void
         */
        public function addEagerConstraints(array $models)
        {
            $key = $this->related->getTable().'.'.$this->foreignKey;

            $whereIn = $this->whereInMethod($this->related, $this->foreignKey);

            $this->query->{$whereIn}($key, $this->getEagerModelKeys($models));
        }

        /**
         * Gather the keys from an array of related models.
         *
         * @param  array  $models
         * @return array
         */
        protected function getEagerModelKeys(array $models)
        {
            $keys = [];
            // First we need to gather all of the keys from the parent models so we know what
            // to query for via the eager loading query. We will add them to an array then
            // execute a "where in" statement to gather up all of those related records.
            foreach ($models as $model) {
                if (is_array($model->{$this->localKey}) && count($model->{$this->localKey}) > 0) {
                foreach($model->{$this->localKey} as $ids){
                        $keys[] = $ids;
                    }
                }
            }
            // If there are no keys that were not null we will just return an array with null
            // so this query wont fail plus returns zero results, which should be what the
            // developer expects to happen in this situation. Otherwise we'll sort them.
            if (count($keys) === 0) {
                return [null];
            }

            sort($keys);

            return array_values(array_unique($keys));
        }

        /**
         * Initialize the relation on a set of models.
         *
         * @param  array   $models
         * @param  string  $relation
         * @return array
         */
        public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
        {
            foreach ($models as $model) {
                $model->setRelation($relation, $this->related->newCollection());
            }

            return $models;
        }

        /**
         * Match the eagerly loaded results to their parents.
         *
         * @param  array   $models
         * @param Collection $results
         * @param  string  $relation
         * @return array
         */
        public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
        {
            return $this->matchOneOrMany($models, $results, $relation, 'one');
        }

        /**
         * Build model dictionary keyed by the relation's foreign key.
         *
         * @param Collection $results
         * @return array
         */
        protected function buildDictionary(Collection $results)
        {
            $foreign = $this->foreignKey;

            return $results->mapToDictionary(function ($result) use ($foreign) {
                    return [$result->{$foreign} => $result];
            })->all();
        }

        protected function getRelationValue(array $dictionary, $key, $type)
        {
            $value = $dictionary[$key];

            return $type === 'one' ? reset($value) : $this->related->newCollection($value);
        }

        protected function matchOneOrMany(array $models, Collection $results, $relation, $type)
        {
            $dictionary = $this->buildDictionary($results);

            if(count($dictionary) > 0){
                $data = [];
                foreach ($models as $model) {
                    foreach($model->getAttribute($this->localKey) as $key){
                        if (array_key_exists($key, $dictionary)) {
                            $data[] = $this->getRelationValue($dictionary, $key, $type);
                                $model->setRelation(
                                $relation, collect(array_unique($data))
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return $models;
        }

        /**
         * Get the results of the relationship.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getResults()
        {
            return $this->get();
        }

        /**
         * Execute the query as a "select" statement.
         *
         * @param  array  $columns
         * @return Collection
         */
        public function get($columns = ['*'])
        {
            // First we'll add the proper select columns onto the query so it is run with
            // the proper columns. Then, we will get the results and hydrate out pivot
            // models with the result of those columns as a separate model relation.
            $columns = $this->query->getQuery()->columns ? [] : $columns;

            if ($columns == ['*']) {
                $columns = [$this->related->getTable().'.*'];
            }

            $builder = $this->query->applyScopes();

            $models = $builder->addSelect($columns)->getModels();

            // If we actually found models we will also eager load any relationships that
            // have been specified as needing to be eager loaded. This will solve the
            // n + 1 query problem for the developer and also increase performance.
            if (count($models) > 0) {
                $models = $builder->eagerLoadRelations($models);
            }

            return $this->related->newCollection($models);
        }
    }
```

We can use this codes like that.

```
$foo = Foo::with(["bar"])->where("id", 1)->first();
$bars = $foo->bar(); // Result is the Eloquent Collection!
$bar = $bars->first(); // Bar::class
```